# Are Convent Schools only for orphan children?

Tags: global-christianity, religious-education

I just want to know whether Convent Schools are only for orphan children? Or can Christian children who have not lost their parents also attend such a school? Can non-Christian children attend a convent school?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be informed that a Convent is the place where Catholic nuns stay in a group. All convents may not necessarily run schools ; Mother Teresa's Convents or the Convents of Missionaries of Charity rarely run schools. Convent schools generally follow the principle of inclusive growth in that they do not differentiate students on the basis of religion,culture,  caste, economic status or other considerations. Of course, the fee-structure in Convent schools may be on the higher side compared with that in Government-run schools. But they also give special considerations for the underprivileged  children.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web... Your answer is OK, but would greatly be enhanced by adding references to reliable sources.

Answer (score 3):

I did my schooling until high school in a convent school.

Answers:

1) No, I'm not a  orphen. This may have cleared you first question but still for your information, convent schools are **open for any students** whose parents  or organisation can effort tuition fees little more than other school under government (and in return  improved facilities and guidance).

2) I'm a Christian but we had **lot more non-Christian students than Christian student** in our school regardlessly orphen or not.

3) Sure, students are selected to the school based on they **abilities and talents** but not caste or religion.

Comment: Unfortunately I guess in India that's not true, in which country you are?

Comment: I'm from Kerala,India.

Comment: I have very bad experience with Malayalam Christians, I considered one Malayalam Christian girl like sister, she has torture me towards Christianity, like force to participate in her festivals etc.

Comment: @KaranGandhi Can't judge all with that incident

Comment: Jesus says "I will love you whether you follow Christianity or not" still people do like this :(

Comment: Anyway you are Java - Android Developer.